# c# webapi query string routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, binding, routes, query-string

Below is my controller and action:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/PaymentManagementController")]
public class PaymentManagementController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public HttpResponseMessage CheckStatus(string commandType, string account, string txnId)
    {
    }
}
```

Here is WebApi.config:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
```

This link is working:

> localhost:59253/api/PaymentManagementController?commandType=check&account=ParamValue1&txnId=SomePrefix0123456789

However, I expected it as:

> localhost:59253/api/PaymentManagementController/CheckStatus?commandType=check&account=ParamValue1&txnId=SomePrefix0123456789

Even after marking Routing as below:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/PaymentManagementController")]
public class PaymentManagementController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("CheckStatus/{commandType}/{account}/{txnId}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage CheckStatus(string commandType, string account, string txnId)
    {
    }
}
```

I receive error as:

> No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'localhost:59253/api/PaymentManagementController?commandType=check&account=ParamValue1&txnId=SomePrefix0123456789'.
>       No action was found on the controller 'PaymentManagement' that matches the request.

Comment: I believe the route you should test for "CheckStatus/{commandType}/{account}/{txnId}"  should be 'localhost:59253/api/PaymentManagementController/CheckStatus/check/ParamValue1/SomePrefix0123456789'  given your second routing, the first one, the controller is working correctly because you assigned null string the route to the method.

Answer (score 1):

Change your route to

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("CheckStatus")]
    public HttpResponseMessage CheckStatus(string commandType, string account, string txnId)
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

as I posted above,

```
[RoutePrefix("api/PaymentManagementController")]
public class PaymentManagementController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("CheckStatus")]
    public HttpResponseMessage CheckStatus(string commandType, string account, string txnId)
    {
    }
```

use the test url:

> localhost:59253/api/PaymentManagementController/CheckStatus?commandType=check&account=ParamValue1&txnId=SomePrefix0123456789

but the second pattern you tried is more modern:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/PaymentManagementController")]
public class PaymentManagementController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("CheckStatus/{commandType}/{account}/{txnId}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage CheckStatus(string commandType, string account, string txnId)
    {
    }
}
```

you should test this using the URL

> localhost:59253/api/PaymentManagementController/CheckStatus/check/ParamValue1/SomePrefix0123456789

Answer (score 1):

You define attributes on your controller and it works as expected using **Attribute Routing**. The defined url in attribute routing works like this : `Route Prefix / Route / Parameters` and for your code it will work for `api/PaymentManagementController?commandType=check&account=ParamValue1&txnId=SomePrefix0123456789`.

To achieve the requested url for work, try this code:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/PaymentManagementController")]
public class PaymentManagementController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("CheckStatus")]
    public HttpResponseMessage CheckStatus(string commandType, string account, string txnId)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove "Controller" from RoutePrefix or remove the whole attribute - controllers are mapped automatically.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/PaymentManagement")]
```

To go with the expected link without controller:

> localhost:59253/api/PaymentManagement/CheckStatus?commandType=check&account=ParamValue1&txnId=SomePrefix0123456789

I would go with:

```
public class PaymentManagementController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage CheckStatus(string commandType, string account, string txnId)
    {
    }
}
```

To go with the expected link with controller:

> localhost:59253/api/PaymentManagementController/CheckStatus?commandType=check&account=ParamValue1&txnId=SomePrefix0123456789

```
public class PaymentManagementControllerController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage CheckStatus(string commandType, string account, string txnId)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try it.
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("CheckStatus")]
    public HttpResponseMessage CheckStatus(string commandType, string account, string txnId)
    {
    }
```

Comment: please try to add the explanation that what you have done in the answer.